# Слово "узнавати" літературне чи калька з російської?

Tags: росіянізм, запозичені-слова, дієслова, чергування

Спершу подумала, що це запозичене, далі - сленг чи, нехай, говірка. Однак, коли звернулася у [СУМ-11](http://sum.in.ua/s/uznavaty), то там все ж його виявила. Невже можна сказати, наприклад: я тебе узнаю?

Цікавить, чи це справді літературне слово, не русизм, адже в російській теж таке є. Про це свідчить, наприклад, і [Тлумачний словник Даля](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/enc2p/367378).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Коротко:

- справді літературне слово;
- схожість — не означає самособно запозичености, особливо для словʼянських слів;
- існує типове для новоукраїнської і літературне чергування *в—у*.

---

Відки рішили, що запозичене? Те, що слова схожі, не завше означає, що хтось відкись запозичив, особливо це стосує ся звичаєвих словʼянських слів. Правда, перезапозичення бувають, але це рідкість. Коли так мислити, то *узнавати* взяте й од польського [*uznawać*](//sjp.pl/uznawa%C4%87), що читає ся дещо як *узнавачь*, так? Тут лиш закінчення ріжнять ся, бо маємо ріжні вигляди неозначених дїєслів, але з московською те саме: там не *узнавати*, а *узнавать*.

Будова слова: *у-зна-ва-ти* — все українського, або, точніше, [загальнословʼянського походження](http://ukraineclub.net/sites/default/files/field/pdf/etymolog_slovnyk_tom2.pdf#page=270).

> Невже можна сказати, наприклад: я тебе узнаю?

Все залежить, яке бачення маєте на чергування *в—у*. Коли підтримуєте подібне, то згадані словники не дуже ріжнять *узнавати* та *взнавати*, отже тут чергування *в—у* припустиме. Як знаємо, таке чергування наразі затверджене для милозвучности, а отже за [чинним правописом](http://litopys.org.ua/pravopys/rozdil1.htm#par11) і лоґікою так сказати не можна, оскільки попереднє слово закінчує ся на голосну **е**, а отже припустимо лиш *взнавати*, тобто:

> Я тебе взнаю?

Comment: Доволі цікаво! Дякую! Так, чомусь, справді подумала, коли випадково побачила це слово.